# Cant install dependencies with composer in Jetbrains

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to install dependencies with composer in JetBrains, but I keep getting the following error when I try to add a dependency...

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe
C:\wamp\www\composer.phar> require aws/aws-sdk-php:2.6.0 -n --no-progress
Failed to install
```

Comment: The line you added is not an error output but the command runned for composer. Do you ahve ny other output ?

Comment: It just says Failed to install

Comment: Does the file composer.phar exist in the marked directory ? You could also try to run that command in your windows command line directly. You can add -vvv for verbose mode or remove the --no-progress and -n which should give more information about whats going on.